# C++11 move constructor slower than C++98 copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-constructor

Let's have a look on three following classes:

```
class IntTab0 {
    private:
        int length;
        int* data;

    public:
        IntTab0(): length(0), data(nullptr) {}

        IntTab0(int size): length(size) {
            assert(size > 0);
            data = new int[length];
        }

        IntTab0(const IntTab0& rhs): length(0), data(nullptr) {
            if (rhs.data) {
                length = rhs.length;
                data = new int(*rhs.data);
            }
        }

        ~IntTab0() {
            delete[] data;
        }

        void swap(IntTab0& second) {
            using std::swap;
            swap(length, second.length);
            swap(data, second.data);
        }
};

class IntTab1 : public IntTab0 {
    public:
        IntTab1(): IntTab0() {}
        IntTab1(int size): IntTab0(size) {}
        IntTab1(const IntTab1& rhs): IntTab0(rhs) {}

        IntTab1(IntTab1&& rhs) noexcept {
            swap(rhs);
        }

        IntTab1& operator=(IntTab1&& rhs) noexcept {
            swap(rhs);
            return *this;
        }
};

class IntTab2 : public IntTab0 {
    public:
        IntTab2(): IntTab0() {}
        IntTab2(int size) : IntTab0(size) {}
        IntTab2(const IntTab2& rhs): IntTab0(rhs) {}

        IntTab2(IntTab2&& rhs) {
            swap(rhs);
        }

        IntTab2& operator=(IntTab2&& rhs) {
            swap(rhs);
            return *this;
        }
};
```

I have also a function to measure a performance each of them:

```
template<class Value>
void test_Performance() {
    std::vector <Value> vit;

    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start, end;
    start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        Value it(5);
        vit.push_back(it);
    }
    std::vector <Value> vitCopy(std::move(vit));

    end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
    std::cout << "elapsed time for IntTab" << it++ << ": " << elapsed_seconds.count() << "s\n";
}
```

What I don't quite understand is the result of running this performance test for each instance of my classes. I suspected IntTab1 should be the fastest one as it uses move constructor and move assignment operator with noexcept. In fact, on my environment results are opposite - the fastest one is the C++98 version using only copy constructor and assignment operator. Here are my results:

> elapsed time for IntTab: 2.2873e-05s
>
> elapsed time for IntTab1: 2.4139e-05s
>
> elapsed time for IntTab2: 2.3554e-05s

Could someone explain this strange behaviour?

#### EDIT

According to comments about wrong copy-constructor (not doing real deep-copy) - I have a testing function which, I assume, tests this behaviour:

```
void test_IntTab( void ) {
    IntTab0 it( 5 );
    it[0] = 10;
    it[4] = 20;
    assert( it.size() == 5 );
    assert( it[0] == 10 );
    assert( it[4] == 20 );

    IntTab0 iu( 10 );
    iu[0] = 17;
    iu[4] = 34;
    assert( iu.size() == 10 );
    assert( iu[0] == 17 );
    assert( iu[4] == 34 );

    iu.swap( it );
    assert( iu.size() == 5 );
    assert( iu[0] == 10 );
    assert( it.size() == 10 );
    assert( it[0] == 17 );

    IntTab0 is( iu );
    assert( is.size() == 5 );
    assert( is[0] == 10 );

    IntTab0 iw;
    iw = it;
    assert( iw.size() == 10 );
    assert( iw[0] == 17 );

    it[0] = 1;
    iu[0] = 2;
    is[0] = 3;
    iw[0] = 4;

    assert( it[0] == 1 );
    assert( iu[0] == 2 );
    assert( is[0] == 3 );
    assert( iw[0] == 4 );
}
```

If my copy-constructor is not working properly, why this function runs correctly?

Comment: How did you compile your code? Also, you're in the range of tens of microseconds. That might have to do with scheduling and other OS-related stuff, not necessarily with bad performance. Try to run for a longer period of time, in the range of seconds preferrably.

Comment: Did you estimate statistical error of measurements? What happens if you rerun the code?

Comment: You have a problem in your copy-constructor. The statement `data = new int(*rhs.data);` allocates *one* integer, and initializes it to `*rhs.data`. Thus doing e.g. `delete[] data` is undefined behavior.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand your code, but your copy constructor for IntTab probably does not do the right thing.

Comment: I don't think you measure anything at all by computing `vitCopy` only once. Do it in a (preferably) long loop. The measurement error is bigger than values you try to measure otherwise.

Comment: In your test, you only test *elem 0* after the copy (just the one you 'copy'), try to test *elem 4*, and you should see the error.

Answer (score 3):

Your copy-constructor doesn't copy the whole data properly.

You don't copy the content in copy-constructor and it just allocates memory. So, it's not complete copy-constructor. This incomplete method should be faster than the move constructor.

```
    IntTab0(const IntTab0& rhs): length(0), data(nullptr) {
        if (rhs.data) {
            length = rhs.length;
            data = new int(*rhs.data);

            ///////////////////////////////////////////
            // Assuming data is an array             //
            // std::copy from rhs.data to this->data //
            ///////////////////////////////////////////
        }
    }
```

If your copy-constructor doesn't have to deep copy members, then moving it has not many advantages rather than copying.

Comment: Thanks. But if my copy-constructor doesn't do deep-copy, why do my testing function run correctly?

Comment: Sheer luck. These kinds of errors are like playing russian roulette: sometimes you get lucky and there's no bullet in the barrel. Try it a few thousand times and the program will break. In your particular case having the program fail silently is bad luck.

Comment: @MateuszKowalski: You're copy constructor should copy the content, use `std::copy` or a `loop` to copy items from `rhs` to itself.